# Perl bindings for Motif Widget Toolkit

Tags: linux, perl, unix, x11, motif

I'm a Motif programmer.  I usually write in C, but I decided to try some higher-level languages.  I tried some C++ bindings, but I realized I don't like that language.

For non GUI programming, I always use Perl, but I didn't found any Motif binding to that language.

Do you know of any?  Can I use Motif library with Perl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[X11-Motif](https://metacpan.org/release/X11-Motif)